# Stuck with prolog program

Tags: prolog

So i encounter a problem with my Prolog problem. let's say you request this:

```
?-num(100,200).
```

The program should return all number from this interval that can generate the number 6 from the reduction theosophique (123=1+2+3=6 so i should return 123, 105 = 1+0+5=6 so i should return it as well. I already have the program that will do the calculation  for this one. i have something and im pretty sure i should work but it doest even run. this is what i got so far the reduct works perfectly

```
num(X,Y):-
    repeat,
    reduct(X,T),
    T=:=6 ->write(X),
    X is X+1,
    (X=:=Y),!.
```

Comment: *i have something and im pretty sure i should work but it doest even run* This sounds a bit like a contradiction, doesn't it? ;) Can you elaborate on "doesn't even run"? Do you get an error message? And did you write code for `reduct`? Also the `=:=` operator determines if two arithmetic expressions are equal when evaluated. You appear to be trying to use it as an assignment statement, which won't work. Prolog doesn't do assignments. It does *unifications*. `X is X+1` will always fail in Prolog because no value of `X` is ever equal to `X+1`.

Comment: i changed it, but it crashes just like before

Comment: Changed it to what? And how did it "crash" before? You're offering very little information. Note when you query, `num(X, Y)` for some values of `X` and `Y`, you cannot change the value of `X` or `Y` in the predicate clause. You have to define a new variable.

Comment: i changed it to T=6 and (X=Y),. yeah when i run the query Swi-Prolog will not respond after that, so i have to close the window and restart it again :(

Comment: and yes i have the code for reduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is little to add to valuable lurker' comments...

Where he suggest

> You appear to be trying to use it as an assignment statement, which won't work. Prolog doesn't do assignments. It does unifications.

you should deduce some implications about *loops*. Your code *cannot* work because it's missing the 'generate' part of 'generate-and-test', that you have coded in a failure driven loop.

So, either add a generator, like between/3, or use recursion, instead of a failure driven loop.

Here is a 1 liner that maybe will help you to complete your assignment.

```
?- [user].
|: num(X,Y) :- between(X,Y,N), number_codes(N,Cs), aggregate(sum(D),C^(member(C,Cs),D is C-0'0),6), writeln(N).

?- num(100,200).
105
true ;
114
true ;
123
true ;
132
true ;
141
true ;
150
true ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to CapelliC's recommendation to use `between/3` (which is ideal for iterating over a range of integers in this case), let's break down your existing predicate to see what's wrong.

**Be mindful of operator precedence**

The ',' is higher than `->`. So your predicate behaves like this:

```
num(X,Y):-
    repeat,
    reduct(X,T),
    T=:=6 ->
    (  write(X),
       X is X+1,
       (X=:=Y), !
    ).
```

As soon as `T =:= 6` fails, you have an infinite loop through, `repeat, reduct(X, T), T =:= 6` since `X` will never change and, therefore, `T` never changes, and so `T =:= 6` continues to fail and Prolog *backtracks* to the `repeat`. In your code, then, this is an infinite loop.

**Your strategy for use of `repeat` and cut (`!`) won't work here**

In form, what you have is:

```
repeat,
<do some queries>,
X =:= Y,    % succeed if X and Y have the same value
!
```

`repeat` always succeeds. Anytime Prolog backtracks all the way back to `repeat`, it will then move forward again looking for more solutions. The cut tells Prolog not to backtrack prior to that point (the point of the cut). The issue here is that `X`, which is already instantiated  (to 100) at the outset from the `num(100, 200)` query call, can never have the same value as `Y` which is set at 200 (see below). So `X =:= Y` will always fail.

**Inside a Prolog predicate clause, a variable cannot be changed except through backtracking and re-unification**

When you query, `num(100, 200)`, from the start `X` and `Y` have been instantiated with 100 and 200, respectively. At that point, the values of `X` and `Y` can now *never* change during the course of that predicate clause execution. The expression `X is X + 1` will *always* fail because Prolog will evaluate `X + 1` and determine if it *is* `X`, which can never be true (in this case, it will always compare 100 with 101).

When you query a predicate in Prolog, say `foo(A, B)`, it seeks to find values for any variables that haven't been set already (they are *uninstantiated*) that make the query *true*. If it finds such values, it succeeds. If it cannot find any, it fails. If you have a series of queries separated by a conjunction (`,`), say, `foo1(A), foo2(A)`, Prolog first queries `foo1(A)` and, if it succeeds, will query `foo2(A)`. If `foo2(A)` fails, Prolog will *backtrack* to `foo1(A)` and try to make it true with some other value of `A` *if `A` was unininstantiated (not set) prior to `foo1(A)`.

**Iterating through an integer range**

In your assignment, you need to iterate from one integer to another (from `X` to `Y` in the `num(X, Y)` query). How can this be done with the restriction that you cannot re-assign a variable in Prolog without backtracking? There is more than one way to do this in Prolog. One clean way is the method CapelliC showed using `between/3`.

```
num(X, Y) :-
    % `between` will first instantiate N with X.
    % On backtracking, it will instantiate N with successive values
    % and succeed until the value exceeds Y. Then it will fail.
    %
    between(X, Y, N),
    <do some calls with N, write out successful values>,
    fail.                  % Automatically backtrack here
```

Another way is recursively:

```
num(X, Y) :-
    % NOTE: if X and Y are given, then their values CANNOT BE CHANGED
    % in this predicate clause!
    %
    X =< Y,                % num(X, Y) succeeds only if X =< Y
    <do some calls with X and/or Y, write successful values>,
    NextX is X + 1,     % New variable whose value is X + 1
    num(NextX, Y).
```

Recursion will continue until `num` sees `X` go greater than `Y` and finally fail.

**Prolog "if-else" construct**

When you want to do an `if` construct, you need to parenthesize to take operator precedence into account:

```
(   <test>
->  <something 1>,         % if test succeeds
    ...
    <something N>
;   <something else 1>,
    ...
    <something else M>
)
```

If you want to just succeed on the "else" case and not do "something else", just do `true`:

```
(   <test>
->  <something 1>,         % if test succeeds
    ...
    <something N>
;   true
)
```

**Generating Results**

The above examples still use your `write` method of displaying results to the user. This isn't really the canonical way to do it in Prolog. Better would be to define a predicate, say, `num(X, Y, R)` which will successively provide values of `R` that make it true when it backtracks. This is a minor modification to the cases above:

```
num(X, Y, R) :-
    % `between` will first instantiate N with X.
    % On backtracking, it will instantiate N with successive values
    % and succeed until the value exceeds Y. Then it will fail.
    %
    between(X, Y, R),
    <do some calls with R>.   % Succeed if R passes criteria
```

Or

```
num(X, Y, X) :-
    % NOTE: if X and Y are given, then their values CANNOT BE CHANGED
    % in this predicate clause!
    %
    X =< Y,                % num(X, Y) succeeds only if X =< Y
    <do some calls with X and/or Y>.    % Succeed if X passes criteria
num(X, Y, R) :-
    X < Y,
    X1 is X + 1,
    num(X1, Y, R).
```

Then each backtrack produces each result:

```
?- num(100,200,R).
R = 105 ;
R = 114 ;
...
false.
```

Comment: WOw thanks a lot for these explanation! i finally have it working!! any tips to master this language? i really suck at it (just like other paradigms), but i really like the challenge to do well on things i find really hard.. like recursion

Comment: @ApexPredator I always tell beginners: try to forget what you know about programming in other languages. It's a bad habit to try to make Prolog work like an imperative, procedural language. Do as many practice problems as possible, but always try to think of your predicates as defining *relations* between variables, not *functions* that compute inputs and outputs. Reading them that way helps: *`num(X, Y)` is true if...* If you really want to learn Prolog, get a good book, like "The Art of Prolog" (Sterling & Shapiro).